# Android dialogs: Should I use a DialogFragment or a separate activity to handle a simple input box

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, dialog

I'm working on a simple Android puzzle game. At the beginning, the game state is determined through the use of a PRNG to generate a random initial game state. However, I'd like to implement a seed system, where the user can enter an alphanumeric string, which will then act as a seed for the PNRG that generates the game's initial state. Users can then share seeds with their friends to play the same board amongst themselves.

In order to do this, I need the Activity that displays the game to display a dialog that has an EditText and an OK button so that the user can enter a seed. The dialog should then send the entered string to the game Activity so it can use it to generate a board. From what I've read, it seems I can either use an Activity with a dialog theme or a DialogFragment for this.

While I could create a dialog themed activity, a separate Activity for this simple purpose seems like overkill, and I can't find a way to return a String to the game Activity from a DialogFragment.

Which way would work better, a separate activity or a DialogFragment. If it's a DialogFragment, what would be the best way to return a String to the game Activity?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In dialog you can get string entered in edit text in a variable and make that variable public static so it can be accessed easily

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple android dialog [popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop). It is very simple to use on your activity.

```
Pop.on(this)
                .with()
                .title(R.string.title)// you can skip if not needed
                .layout(R.layout.custom_pop)// your custom layout 
                .when(new Pop.Yah() { // positive button
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yah button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .when(new Pop.Nah() { // negative button, you can skip if not neeed
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nah button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).show();
```